# Does a following consonant cancel the preceding consonant?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

[According to a tutorial](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=578), we can link **/d/** to **/t/** or **/t/** to **/d/** in speech, for example,

> I need **t**wo kilos of shrimp.

the /t/ sound in "two" cancels the /d/ sound in "need".

> She asked **D**ave what would happen.

the /d/ sound in "Dave" cancels the /t/ sound in "asked".

In conclusion, for /d/ and /t/, the sound at the beginning of the following word cancels the sound at the end of the preceding word.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "I nee two kilos of shrimp" and "She ask Dave what would happen" .....is that what you mean?  I don't have an answer but my British accent semi-enunciates the start of the d sound in need two but, unless I pause deliberately, I can say the second as I have written and it does seem to sound identical to asked Dave.

Comment: I don't think it cancels completely.  You seem to start the sound but you don't complete it.  Here in Brazil we have a nasal sound ão, as in São Paulo.  I was taught to enunciate ão  as if I were saying 'town' (Like towns and cities!) but to stop short of fully completing the n sound.  And to do this while pretending to have a cold.

Answer (score 1):

Some consonant clusters do drop elements completely, especially in rapid speech; but more often they are all there, but only the last is released.

So in rapid speech *asked Dave* and *ask Dave* both may sound the same - they lose the /k/ as well as the first /d/ in the former: /aːsdɛɪv/ in my dialect. In slightly more careful speech, the /k/ is still absent, but the two sound different because there is an unreleased /d/ in the former, resulting in to the geminate /aːsdːɛɪv/.

Slowing down further, the /k/ becomes audible, but again unreleased - the cluster is /k͡d/, which begins with the velar closure of /k/, but the tongue moves before the release, so that the it is /d/ which is released. But the two are still distinct, with a longer interval before the release in "asked Dave".

Finally, in very careful speech, all the consonants will be pronounced (and released) individually.